# How to get Real Time Stock Market Data using investpy?

Tags: python, data-science

I've been able to extract daily, weekly and monthly data from the website but how can I extract tick data using the library investpy ?

The teacher refused to answer my question and I'm literally dying rn xD

thanks.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import investpy

df=investpy.get_stock_historical_data(stock="AB", country = "tunisia", from_date = "1/1/2019", to_date = "22/2/2021")
print(df)
```

Comment: You really should show some of the code you have and maybe what you have tried so that a person can give you a better answer.

Comment: @Vincent Done ! sorry it's my first time posting here. thanks for making things clear <3

Comment: The stocks module has a function that mentions "real time": https://investpy.readthedocs.io/_api/stocks.html?highlight=real%20time#investpy.stocks.get_stocks_overview

Comment: `df_real = investpy.stocks.get_stocks_overview(country="tunisia", as_json=False, n_results=10)` It seems that the only way to accumulate data is to run this on a regular basis.

Comment: @jezi Hedi, did you find an answer?